# Spring Security - Access is denied (user is not anonymous) spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

can anyone see an failure in this Spring Security Config File?

After Login the i get a debug message:

> Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to
>   AccessDeniedHandler
>   org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is
>   denied

but I can access the application.

```
     @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
      authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register/verification/*/*").anonymous()
      .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register/test").anonymous()
      .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register").anonymous()
      .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/forgot_password").anonymous().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/triggeredBy/password**").permitAll()
      .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/err/403").permitAll()
      .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
      .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/landingPage", true).failureUrl("/login?error=true").usernameParameter(
      "username").passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and()
      .rememberMe().rememberMeCookieName("REMEMBER_ME").rememberMeParameter("remember_me").tokenValiditySeconds(123456).key(
      "49874795145977617241")
      .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/err/403");
  }
```

Stacktrace:

```
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/js/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/forgot_password'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/err/403'; against '/js/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/triggeredby/password**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/err/403'; against '/img/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/images/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/err/403'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/err/403'; against '/fonts/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/err/403'; against '/favicon.ico'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [anonymous]
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@18b68a6c: Principal: de.upb.msapp.web.model.profiles.Profile@2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2eb76: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E46776770A1C922CDF1A00121BB6A4E3; Granted Authorities: ROLE_PATIENT, ROLE_PROFILE
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/error'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5b5cddbb, returned: -1
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/static/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/resources/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /err/403' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/uploads/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/css/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /err/403' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/js/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.826 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/img/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/fonts/**'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/favicon.ico'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.s.w.a.r.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter : SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@18b68a6c: Principal: de.upb.msapp.web.model.profiles.Profile@2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2eb76: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E46776770A1C922CDF1A00121BB6A4E3; Granted Authorities: ROLE_PATIENT, ROLE_PROFILE'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /err/403 at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@18b68a6c: Principal: de.upb.msapp.web.model.profiles.Profile@2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2eb76: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E46776770A1C922CDF1A00121BB6A4E3; Granted Authorities: ROLE_PATIENT, ROLE_PROFILE'
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]

2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-11 12:09:17.827 DEBUG 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
```

Comment: Which request mapping do you access, when you receive the error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#anonymous--)

> **anonymous()**
>      Specify that URLs are allowed by anonymous users.

---

Lets take a look at some of your code:

```
.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
```

You are telling the system to allow only anonymous users (`ROLE_ANONYMOUS`) to be able to call the `/login` mapping.

When you login with your user, the user has another role and is not anonymous anymore. For this code example you should use `permitAll()`.

Most likely you also want to use `permitAll()` on other request matchers and in your case I would also use only one mapping for `/login`--> `formLogin()`.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me - `hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")`

Try with `@RolesAllowed("USER")` instead of `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")`.
Eventually you could use `hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")` or `hasRole("USER")` instead of `hasRole("ROLE_USER")` .

Comment: For me hasRole("ROLE_USER") ie adding ROLE_ made the error go away. Maybe It's due to the spring version used I think .. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

try below code. it worked for me.

```
     http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()

    .antMatchers("/login**", "/").permitAll()        
    .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasAnyAuthority('USER')")
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')")

    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that the

> img.img-rounded.img-responsive(alt='Avatar',
>   src="#{_contextPath}#{profile.avatarPath}")

was wrong. After getting the right path it works for me.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: But it was the solution to the problem. Why I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting this URL as ignored by security ?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/layouts/**", "/styles/**", "/spring/login");
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in my case, I needed to set anonymous role. So in spring-security.xml, following anonymous role was added and the bean.

access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_MYAPP_SERVICE','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"

<bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="key"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg value="key"/>
    </bean>
```