# Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am new to Spring Security. I am trying to add LDAP authentication to a Spring Web app. I set up a test LDAP server and trying to authenticate the web app using it. But somehow, when I enter username and password in the login page, I keep getting this error.

Following is my **WebSecurityConfig.java** file:

```
package com.logsniffer.web.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; 
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},cn=admin,ou=support,dc=ldap,dc=com")
            .contextSource()
            .port(389)
            .url("ldap://localhost")
            .managerDn("cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com")
            .managerPassword("thresh143");
    }
}
```

I enabled the debug logs and my stack trace is shown below.

```
    016-09-11 20:25:09,608 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,612 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,613 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No HttpSession currently exists
2016-09-11 20:25:09,613 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-09-11 20:25:09,617 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,618 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@9a6237a
2016-09-11 20:25:09,618 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,618 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,618 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,619 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-09-11 20:25:09,619 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,619 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,619 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,621 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,622 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,623 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,623 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter] Requested session ID 1f9bsaf2s4smc1qgbhwob9rv0p is invalid.
2016-09-11 20:25:09,623 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,623 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] / at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,624 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [authenticated]
2016-09-11 20:25:09,625 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-09-11 20:25:09,631 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3e7987f7, returned: -1
2016-09-11 20:25:09,641 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:162)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-09-11 20:25:09,646 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher] Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2016-09-11 20:25:09,646 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,647 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher] matches = true
2016-09-11 20:25:09,647 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher] Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@784167fc, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2016-09-11 20:25:09,653 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] Processing text/html
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] application/json .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] Processing application/xhtml+xml
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] Processing application/xml;q=0.9
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] Processing */*;q=0.8
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] Ignoring
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher] Did not match any media types
2016-09-11 20:25:09,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher] matches = true
2016-09-11 20:25:09,655 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher] Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
2016-09-11 20:25:09,655 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher] matches = true
2016-09-11 20:25:09,655 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher] All requestMatchers returned true
2016-09-11 20:25:09,669 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache] DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8082/]
2016-09-11 20:25:09,669 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] Calling Authentication entry point.
2016-09-11 20:25:09,670 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy] Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8082/login'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,670 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-09-11 20:25:09,674 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-09-11 20:25:09,680 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,680 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,680 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-09-11 20:25:09,680 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:17btgxu8eozffd9lq5nj9wzbv@2100204867. A new one will be created.
2016-09-11 20:25:09,680 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,680 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@9a6237a
2016-09-11 20:25:09,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-09-11 20:25:09,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:09,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-09-11 20:25:09,687 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-09-11 20:25:13,812 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:17btgxu8eozffd9lq5nj9wzbv@2100204867. A new one will be created.
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@9a6237a
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] Request is to process authentication
2016-09-11 20:25:13,818 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager] Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
2016-09-11 20:25:13,819 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider] Processing authentication request for user: sramasinghe
2016-09-11 20:25:13,829 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator] Attempting to bind as uid=sramasinghe,ou=support,dc=ldap,dc=com,dc=ldap,dc=com
2016-09-11 20:25:13,829 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource] Removing pooling flag for user uid=sramasinghe,ou=support,dc=ldap,dc=com,dc=ldap,dc=com
2016-09-11 20:25:13,839 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator] Failed to bind as uid=sramasinghe,ou=support,dc=ldap,dc=com: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
2016-09-11 20:25:13,839 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
2016-09-11 20:25:13,840 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2016-09-11 20:25:13,840 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@29fe65da
2016-09-11 20:25:13,840 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler] Redirecting to /login?error
2016-09-11 20:25:13,840 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy] Redirecting to '/login?error'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,840 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-09-11 20:25:13,840 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-09-11 20:25:13,853 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login?error at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login?error at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:17btgxu8eozffd9lq5nj9wzbv@2100204867. A new one will be created.
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login?error at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@9a6237a
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login?error at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login?error at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login?error at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,854 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-09-11 20:25:13,855 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-09-11 20:25:13,916 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession:17btgxu8eozffd9lq5nj9wzbv@2100204867. A new one will be created.
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@9a6237a
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-09-11 20:25:13,918 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: What is the URL for the login page ?. Also for which URL are you getting access denied ?

Comment: URL for the login is localhost:8082/login
URL for the home page is localhost:8082/

Comment: I might be wrong but I think this has to do something with the Spring configuration. See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719446/spring-security-access-is-denied-user-is-not-anonymous-spring-security-core

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It was due to way I initialized auth object in configureGlobal. I will update the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but since I'm experiencing similar trouble I reached here and while looking at the code I find this line:

`2016-09-11 20:25:13,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login`

, alarming that /login is not matched due to method configuration.

I'd check also UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler impelemntations and behaviour.