# Spring boot x509 Mutual Authentication - AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement client authentication[Mutual Authentication] in spring boot. When implementing SSL without client certificate it works fine. But when trying to implement client authentication by getting the client certificate I get:

> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is
>   denied

This is the complete stack trace of the exception.

```
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 29 ms
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /test' doesn't match 'POST /logout
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /test' doesn't match 'POST /login
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6937fd2c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff8868: RemoteIpAddress: 172.17.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /test; Attributes: [authenticated]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6937fd2c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff8868: RemoteIpAddress: 172.17.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@755906f7, returned: -1
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:206) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]

o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/test' matched by universal pattern '/**'
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing */*
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Ignoring
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Did not match any media types
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : All requestMatchers returned true
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[https://localhost/test]
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using AndRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]]
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing */*
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Ignoring
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Did not match any media types
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], AndRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]]
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using AndRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]]
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing */*
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : text/html .isCompatibleWith */* = true
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = false
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5766c6e, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing */*
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : isEqualTo true
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@3059cbc
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@268c08ca
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@4d10b37e. A new one will be created.
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /login
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: both null (property equals)
o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/test; arg2=/error (property not equals)
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@5e238d94: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 172.17.0.1; SessionId: A43E9A5D4EF79BBDF929D83AB3B77362; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

This is the class file

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("localhost").password("none").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().x509()
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

My application.properties file

```
server.port: 443
server.ssl.key-store: newcerts/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: changeit
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.trust-store: newcerts/truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password: changeit
server.ssl.client-auth: need
logging.level.org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

I created the certs and added the code by following the instructions in this page:
[https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/08/x-509-client-certificates-with-spring-security/][1]

When I do a curl request

> curl -ik --cert newcerts/client.crt --key newcerts/clientprivate.key
>   "https://localhost:443/test"

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A43E9A5D4EF79BBDF929D83AB3B77362; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 01 Oct 2018 14:40:00 GMT

{"timestamp":"2018-10-01T14:40:00.738+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/test"}
```

I also looked at the following questions :

[[Spring Security - Access is denied (user is not anonymous) spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719446/spring-security-access-is-denied-user-is-not-anonymous-spring-security-core][2])

These are the steps I followed there for Server Cert:

```
1. openssl genrsa -aes256 -out serverprivate.key 2048
2. openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key serverprivate.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out serverCA.crt
3. keytool -import -file serverCA.crt -alias serverCA -keystore truststore.jks
4. openssl pkcs12 -export -in serverCA.crt -inkey serverprivate.key -certfile serverCA.crt -out keystore.p12
5. keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

--- For Client Certificate ---

```
1. openssl genrsa -aes256 -out clientprivate.key 2048 
2. openssl req -new -key clientprivate.key -out client.csr 
3. openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA serverCA.crt -CAkey serverprivate.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

Comment: Did you import the client cert to trust store?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I imported the CA cert to the truststore. In another case I just created a Key for the server and used it to sign the server cert as well as the client cert.

Comment: @dur I am using the 2.0.3.Release [I looked it up in my pom.xml]

Comment: In mutual auth, server will get client certificate public key and verifies whether subject of client cert is allowed or not. Below example has configured to allow any certs.
`@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .x509()
            .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }`
https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security. Let me know if this works, I will paste the answer.

Comment: @Imran: Your configruation is the default configuration and should not be neccessary.

Comment: @Akhil: I can't see `X509AuthenticationFilter` in your logs, so I doubt that your configuration is applied. Try to add `@Configuration` to your class.

Comment: @dur I'll try that. In the meanwhile I removed the spring security part from my project and just kept the client-certificate ssl information in the application.properties file and it worked. But when I copy all these files and move them to a new computer and try from there I am getting a "error reading x.509 key or certificate file: decryption has failed". Does the private key file get corrupted if i copy them to some other place and use the same?

Comment: @Akhil: No, it should work. Check your configuration, maybe some path, key or password is wrong.